# form api #default_value not picked up

Tags: forms

I have a form which I have altered with hook_form _alter to set the #default_value. It works for most fields, but for some reason some are defaulting to the second value of the list. I did a dpm() and looked at the form structure, and #default_value is set correctly.

Any ideas?
The only other thing I might add: the source of the form is from the Addressfield module. I needed to hack it and add extra format handlers. It works perfectly, but again, #defaul_value has been giving me issues.

EDIT:
Here is the hook form alter code:

```
$form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['howDidYouHear_block']['howDidYouHear']['#default_value'] = "Other Reason";
```

Comment: "I have altered with hook_form _alter to set the #default_value." - cool, but if you want help with your code, why can't we see this code?

Comment: I made the edit and added it